# video not display in Recyclerview from web url using Toro video library

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, video-streaming

I'm working on a project that involves displaying a list of videos from the backend using retrofit, i want to display the video with some data on the UI using recyclerview, i'm trying to use TORO video library to handle the video but instead of displaying the video the video space is blank and black and other info apart the video was displayed successfully.
What i want is proper usage of the library if i'm getting it wrong, or link to other library that you have tested that i could use or how you do it in your own project if you have done it before.

check adapter code below used with the library.

```
package com.theproject.allClass.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.klinker.android.simple_videoview.SimpleVideoView;
import com.theproject.R;
import com.theproject.allClass.api.model.AuditionRoom;
import com.theproject.allClass.api.model.Timeline;

import java.util.List;

import im.ene.toro.ToroPlayer;
import im.ene.toro.ToroUtil;
import im.ene.toro.exoplayer.SimpleExoPlayerViewHelper;
import im.ene.toro.media.PlaybackInfo;
import im.ene.toro.widget.Container;

public class AuditionRoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AuditionRoomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<AuditionRoom> data;

    public AuditionRoomAdapter(Context context, List<AuditionRoom> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.audition_timeline, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.username.setText(data.get(position).getUsername());
        holder.userPostText.setText(data.get(position).getUserMessage());
        holder.yes.setText(""+data.get(position).getYes_votes_count());
        holder.no.setText(""+data.get(position).getNo_votes_count());
        Glide.with(context).load(data.get(position).getUserProfilepicUrl()).into(holder.userProfilePic);
//        Glide.with(context).load(data.get(position).getUpload_file_url()).into(holder.userPostImage);
        holder.bind(Uri.parse(data.get(position).getUpload_file_url()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ToroPlayer{

        TextView username;
        TextView userPostText;
        TextView yes;
        TextView no;
        ImageView userProfilePic;
        ImageView userPostImage;
        SimpleExoPlayerView playerView;
        SimpleExoPlayerViewHelper helper;
        Uri mediaUri;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            userProfilePic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.audition_user_profile_pic);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.audition_user_name);
            userPostText =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.audition_user_post_text);
            //userPostImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.audition_user_post_image);
            playerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.player);

            yes =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.audition_yes_figure);
            no = itemView.findViewById(R.id.audition_no_figure);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getPlayerView() {
            return playerView;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PlaybackInfo getCurrentPlaybackInfo() {
            return helper != null ? helper.getLatestPlaybackInfo() : new PlaybackInfo();
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(@NonNull Container container, @Nullable PlaybackInfo playbackInfo) {
            if (helper == null) {
                helper = new SimpleExoPlayerViewHelper(container, this, mediaUri);
            }
            helper.initialize(playbackInfo);
        }

        @Override
        public void play() {
            if (helper != null) helper.play();
        }

        @Override
        public void pause() {
            if (helper != null) helper.pause();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isPlaying() {
            return helper != null && helper.isPlaying();
        }

        @Override
        public void release() {
            if (helper != null) {
                helper.release();
                helper = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean wantsToPlay() {
            return ToroUtil.visibleAreaOffset(this, itemView.getParent()) >= 0.85;
        }

        @Override
        public int getPlayerOrder() {
            return getAdapterPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSettled(Container container) {

        }

        // called from Adapter to setup the media
        void bind(Uri item) {
            if (item != null) {
                mediaUri = item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[The result of the recyclerview with video not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUncq.png)
link to the library on github
    https://github.com/eneim/toro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to solve the issue by adding the schema(http or https) to the loading url, TORO library is good for displaying video on a recyclerview, tested and confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error but I resolved it by adding
`Container` instead of `RecycerView`.

```
<im.ene.toro.widget.Container android:id="@+id/recyleVideo" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```